# Can ThreadSafe errors for ScriptingAdditions be eliminated without deleting the addition files?

Tags: macos, pages, logs, console

I've the following errors in my system log when running e.g. Pages:

```
Aug  4 19:06:50 Pages[9751]: Performance: Please update this scripting addition to supply a value for ThreadSafe for each event handler: "/Library/ScriptingAdditions/MySpeed.osax"
Aug  4 19:06:50 Pages[9751]: Performance: Please update this scripting addition to supply a value for ThreadSafe for each event handler: "/Library/ScriptingAdditions/SIMBL.osax"
```

What is the cause of that and how do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As workaround, InjectEventHandler handler can be removed or commented out from Info.plist from the files:

```
/Library/ScriptingAdditions/SIMBL.osax/Contents/Info.plist
/Library/ScriptingAdditions/MySpeed.osax/Contents/Info.plist
```

Source:
https://code.google.com/p/simbl/issues/detail?id=7

In example:

```
--- a/Info.plist
+++ b/Info.plist
@@ -37,8 +37,6 @@
                <key>Context</key>
                <string>Process</string>
            </dict>
-           <key>SIMeleop</key>
-           <string>InjectEventHandler</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
 </dict>
```

Or you can also try to set ThreadSafe to true:
E.g.

```
<key>OSAXHandlers</key>
<dict>
    <key>Events</key>
    <dict>
        <key>sysodlog</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Handler</key>
            <string>DisplayDialogEventHandler</string>
            <key>ThreadSafe</key>
            <true/>
            <key>Context</key>
            <string>Process</string>
        </dict> 
...
```

> Handler dictionary keys:
>
> ThreadSafe - A boolean; is the handler
>   thread-safe? (Event handlers only.)
>
> ThreadSafe OSA and AppleScript in Mac OS X v10.6 are thread-safe. If a
>   script is executed on a background thread and invokes an event handler
>   that is not thread-safe, it will be called on the main thread, which
>   is slower than directly invoking it on the calling thread and may
>   reduce application responsiveness to user input. Ideally, all handlers
>   should be thread-safe. Some inherently cannot be; for example, almost
>   anything that displays UI must be executed on the main thread. You are
>   encouraged to either verify that your event handlers are thread-safe
>   or update them to make them thread-safe.
>
> If the value of this key is true, then the handler may be executed on
>   a non-main thread and it may be executed concurrently from multiple
>   threads. If false, it will only be executed on the main thread. This
>   key is required for event handlers, and must not be present for
>   coercion handlers, which are required to be thread-safe. If a coercion
>   handler cannot be made safe to run on background threads, the handler
>   must arrange to execute the coercion on the main thread, such as using
>   by using libdispatch and the main dispatch queue.

Read more:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn1164/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003003-CH1-MAC_OS_X_V10_6__SNOW_LEOPARD__AND_LATER__INFO_PLIST

Related issues:

https://code.google.com/p/simbl/issues/detail?id=7
https://code.google.com/p/simbl/issues/detail?id=38

Other:

https://code.google.com/p/simbl/issues/detail?id=14
https://code.google.com/p/simbl/issues/detail?id=66
https://code.google.com/p/simbl/issues/detail?id=67
https://code.google.com/p/afloat/issues/detail?id=43